# How do I import the Dart IndexedDB library in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, indexeddb

I am using following statement to import dart indexed db library in Flutter application:

```
import 'dart:indexed_db';
```

VSCode reports following error:

```
Target of URI doesn't exist: 'dart:indexeddb'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does 
exist.dart(uri_does_not_exist)
```

How to use indexed db in Flutter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this issue: [indexedDB blocked](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44937)

indexedDB is *blocked* in flutter

you could use an alternative like [idb_shim](https://pub.dev/packages/idb_shim) which is simply a wrapper for indexedDB API

Comment: Thanks. Used sembast_web: ^2.0.0+2